# Открыть WhatsApp с параметром

Tags: c#, процесс

При запуске WhatsApp с параметром [https://chat.whatsapp.com/какой-та](https://chat.whatsapp.com/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0) ключ",
запускается каждый раз другой экземпляр WhatsApp. Что не очень удобно. Если делать через браузер Мозила, то открывает уже запущенный WhatsApp. В интернете так и не нашел ответ. 
Мой код:

```
Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\WhatsApp\\WhatsApp.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = line2;
        proc.Start();
```

Comment: Ну так `new Process` какбэ намекает, что вы просите создать новый процесс... чего удивляться, что так оно и выполняется? Попробуйте вместо этого поискать существующий, каким-нить GetProcess-ом или около того, и общаться с ним (или одним из них, буде их уже несколько)... и только при неудаче создавайте новый.

Comment: @Akina Я пытался через GetProcessByName, но что то не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может кому пригодится или нет, но все же помучился я некоторое время и нашел решения на свой вопрос. Ответ заключался в том, что я неправильные аргументы передавал, вместо аргумента "https://chat.whatsapp.com/invite/KEY", нужно передать аргумент такого содержания "whatsapp://chat?code=KEY" и тогда все будет работать. Будет запускать одно окно, если окно запущенно, то просто покажет его и присоединиться к группе.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"<DIR>\WhatsApp.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "whatsapp://chat?code=" + keys;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Спасибо, мне очень помог твой ответ на данный вопрос.